# Search for questions by user (with sample queries)?

Tags: support, tag-search

I'm trying to search for questions by me containing the word jquery, search string `user:69724 jquery`.  SO is returning no results.  I believe it is not searching the tags field because when I query for `user:69724 php`, I get only one result and php is in the body.  Believing I've surely asked more than one php question, I tried `user:69724 [php]` (note: [tag] in search according to Advanced Search Tips).  Now I still have 1 results.  Am I searching wrong, or do I just have 0 questions containing the tag jquery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You got the user-id wrong. Anyway, instead of writing it explicitly and possibly getting it wrong, use `user:me`.

Example: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3Ame+jquery

Comment: Or click on your profile page, where it is auto-filled in the search box.